# How to make installer of java desktop application for multi-platform?

Tags: java, installation, cross-platform, multiplatform

How could we made a jar file's installer, which can run on multi-platform. Is there any simple way, because I don't know Java much well.

Balwant

Comment: I'm really waiting for lots of good answers on this one :)

Comment: For the record, link to the accompanying question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979451/auto-startup-for-java-desktop-application

Answer (score 4):

Installer tools for Java have been dealt with in quite many questions on SO, and most options have probably been mentioned already:

- [What’s the best way to distribute Java applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-java-applications)
- [Java Application Installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184060/java-application-installers)
- [What is the best installation tool for java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173392/what-is-the-best-installation-tool-for-java)

See also other questions [tagged java+installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+installer).

If a commercial tool is ok, the best multi-platform installer for Java software, to my knowledge, is [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html); I can definitely recommend it ([more about my experiences with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application/786307#786307)).

Answer (score 2):

Nearly half of our [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) customers use it for Java deployment. It is multiplatform and runs in all the major platforms such as Windows, Linux, Mac, Solaris, HP-UX (and most of the obscure ones too :)

Comment: I did  some comparison with few of them please also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979451/auto-startup-for-java-desktop-application/5549910#5549910

Answer (score 1):

[izPack](http://izpack.org/) is pretty nifty and supports multi-platform installations.

Answer (score 1):

If the target audience have access to the web, you could have a look on Java Web Start which allows you to basically do all you need.

It requires the user to click a link and download.

Answer (score 0):

Well the best way is to use InstallAnywhere that is good for install or packagging any of the applicaion in desktop.

here the[InstallAnywhere](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallAnywhere-Premier) go to site register your self and download one trial verson.