# making a batch file to install a program

Tags: java, deployment, batch-file, installation

One of my friend told me that he used a batch program to install a java program on the machine,that placed the necessary files in a particular directory and also planted a shortcut on the desktop. How can it be done ? If there are tutorials that teach this please link me to them

Comment: A batch file can run commands and commands can move files around. What platform do you want to install on?

Comment: Why to write it on our own, why don't [just reuse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979572/how-to-make-installer-of-java-desktop-application-for-multi-platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use some basic windows commands to make this work. I'm not going to write the script for you but I can point you in the right direction. A batch script on windows is a simple text file ending with the `.bat` extension. 
You can use any command typically available on the windows command prompt (AKA `cmd.exe`). A good starting point is learning how to move and copy files around so you want to take a look at the commands by the same name on the [Command-line reference from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true). There is also a handy guide linked on the same page to [batch files and how they work](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true).

The documentation linked is for Widows XP and the syntax of the commands should be back and forwards compatible with other Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a Java program is the same thing as installing a ... program ;-)
You can create a batch installer from scratch with a .bat file or use an installer builder tool.
I use NSIS because it's free and simple to use ... but there's others.

You also may want to build an .exe instead of a jar file (sometime, windows open the jar archives instead of launching java). I use Launch4J to wrap my java application in a .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

If the app. has a GUI, install/launch it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  It works on Windows, OS X & *nix, and can install both desktop shortcuts and menu items to launch the app. on platforms that support such things.

JWS is supported & supplied by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a simple batch script. Customize this code.

Code:

```
@echo off
color f0
:: overwrite your program name after the '=' ::
set ProgramNameHere=ProgramNameHere
goto start
:start
cd/
cd users
cd %username%
cd desktop
md %ProgramNameHere%
:: overwrite your file path on the 'DATA' ::
:: overwrite your file name on the 'file1', 'file2'...
:: overwritw your file name after the 'extracting'.
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file1.txt
echo extracting file 1
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file2.txt
echo extracting file 2
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file3.txt
echo extracting file 3
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file4.txt
echo extracting file 4
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file5.txt
echo extracting file 5
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file6.txt
echo extracting file 6
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file7.txt
echo extracting file 7
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file8.txt
echo extracting file 8
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file9.txt
echo extracting file 9
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file10.txt
echo extracting file 10
ping localhost>nul
goto exit

:exit
exit
```