# How to inform the user of downloading the document in java?

Tags: java

How to inform the user that the document is downloaded to `C: / ../Downloads` on the browser.

I use the java library `XWPFDocument` or other solutions .

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would have an installer which would ask you if you would like the file to be placed in the drive. (at least for windows.)

Here on Stack Overflow, I found [How to make installer of java desktop application for multi-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979572/how-to-make-installer-of-java-desktop-application-for-multi-platform)

Otherwise building your program a website and telling them there wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I do not want to install applications on the pc to inform download.
I want a dynamic code is better. I already use the web java with spring MVC and spring boot. Possible @MULTI Team !

Comment: I found that :
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+Path+"/Downloads/table.doc");`                                       Is it functional for all Unix systems, windows ...?