# How to start a Java Jar when windows starts?

Tags: java, windows, permissions, registry, startup

I read you can add a key to the registry, but there are permission problems on Windows Vista and 7. What's the safest & best way to start a Java program on System startup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for Auto starting a java application on windows startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025807/code-for-auto-starting-a-java-application-on-windows-startup)

Answer (score 4):

You can setup a Java service wrapper to start a Java application on windows startup.
http://www.google.com/search?q=java+service+wrapper

Comment: Thanks, a service is an overkill, I am building a desktop application. I was wondering if using the registry is the best way because of the permission problems in Vista/7. Or should I use the Windows startup folder.

Comment: The windows starup folder only runs when a user logs in not on System startup. Coming from a Java/unix background I wouldn't recommend messing with the registry if you can help it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the Task Scheduler, have it run:

> java -jar file.jar

And set it to run on computer startup, and to run with the highest privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna do this on code or manually ?

But is all about the Registry, why don't you check the Java Service Wrapper ?

Answer (score 0):

winsw works very nicely: http://kenai.com/projects/winsw

(requires .NET though)