# How to make a Java app automatically start when PC starts?

Tags: java, windows

I'm developing a scheduling app, it reminds user of things to do during a day, it checks every minute to see if time is up, and if it is it will open an alert window to remind the user. Although it's written in Java, I'm targeting Windows users for this app. It needs to run as soon as users' PCs are turned on, so my question is: How to make a Java app automatically start when a PC is turned on in a Windows system?

I know I can go through a few steps manually to add the app to start-up apps list, but not every user is familiar with the steps, so I wonder if it can do this through my Java program, and if so is there any sample code?

Comment: Hm... I just got a sensation of Déjà vu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564813/how-to-start-a-java-jar-when-windows-starts and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025807/code-for-auto-starting-a-java-application-on-windows-startup

Comment: windows scheduler can do it I suppose. Call java program from windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto startup for java desktop application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979451/auto-startup-for-java-desktop-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a .bat file

```
@javaw -jar path/to/jar/Name.jar arguments
```

drop this in you startup directory

Comment: This will work :) Make sure that you have a MANIFEST.MF, with your main class defined.

Comment: <1> Can my Java program save the above file into the Windows startup directory ?
<2> Where is this Windows startup directory on the C: or D: drive ?
<3> How can my Java app find out the location ?
<4> Is it the same on all versions of Windows ?

Comment: @frank <1> Use notepad to create the .bat file <2> I think %USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup is the directory. you could also use %ALLUSERSPROFILE% if you want it to be there for everyone <3> I have no idea what this means. How can your app find what location? <4> I have no idea. I stopped using cancerOS in '05.

Comment: This only works after you login, not directly after computer reboot.

Comment: @MichaelMunsey True. Also irrelevant. Since the purpose is to notify a logged in user of things, one has to be logged in to make use of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html). Set `wrapper.ntservice.starttype=DEMAND_START` in [wrapper configuration](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-starttype.html).