# How to find where the Startup folder is with Java?

Tags: java, windows, startup-folder

In my Java program how can I find out where the Startup folder is on uers' PCs ? I know it's different on different versions of Windows. I only need my app to work on Windows. Any sample code ?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java ?

Comment: why do you need to find the start up folder on windows? Do you want your application to run at windows start up?

Comment: @Ram : See my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565639/how-to-make-a-java-app-automatically-start-when-pc-starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

here you have an overviwe about system properties:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Didn't work. It should be something like this : C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: Then what's the varying variable? the username?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, I want to find out where the startup folder is on users' PCs, so what property should I look for ? Or is there such a property ? I know the location of this folder is different on different versions of Windows. But there is no such a property as : user.startup_folder

Comment: I figured it out, it's a combination of user.dir and user.home

Answer (score 1):

With ShellLink creating shortcuts is very simple. https://github.com/BlackOverlord666/mslinks

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.vatbub</groupId>
  <artifactId>mslinks</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer answer by https://stackoverflow.com/a/38952899/4697928

```
private final String STARTUP_PATH = "/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup";

private void checkAutoStartPresent() {
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + STARTUP_PATH + "/YourShortcutFileName.lnk");
    if (!file.exists()) { // shortcut not found
        try {
            ShellLink.createLink("/YourTargetProgramPath.exe", file.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```