# Load desktop application on Windows startup

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application

I have Java desktop application, which runs fine. I can double click on exe or run jar file and runs properly.

I want to load this application whenever system starts. How can I achieve this programmatically?

Or is there any tool available to create exe in such a manner, that once we install it creates shortcut in system startup folder.

I want it be system or code driven rather than individually placing exe in startup folder.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup) and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564813/how-to-start-a-java-jar-when-windows-starts) it migth help you.

Comment: @edasssus already checked, but does not help much, does not makes clear if i need to do programmatically or use any tool for that.

Comment: can't to try setting it up as an automatic windows service?

Comment: @Sampada yes how cani do that, i created exe using Excelsior software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up the exe as a windows service with these steps:

1. open command prompt as administrator
2. type this:

> sc.exe create `<service_name>` binPath= "`<path to your exe>` --service" DisplayName= "`<somename>`" start= "auto"

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my problem is i want to deploy this exe on other system, they will download and just install. I cannot ask them to place manually or run command, i just want them to double click and install, and it should install as a service.

Comment: create a batch file with first instruction to run the exe and then this commnad. Ask people to run the batch file to install your exe .

Comment: ok got it, will try as per your suggestion.