# Run Jar file on PC at startup

Tags: java, windows, jar, startup

I know that similar questions were asked before here. But I couldn't make mine work somehow. Here are the steps that I tried already.

1. I created a bat file as `javaw -Xmx200m -jar C:\Path\to\jarfile\TheJar.jar` and put in the startup folder. It worked for the current user. This doesn't help because I want to run this file for all users once they login to PC.
2. I created key value as HKEY_local_machine>software>microsoft>windows>current version >run and put it the samething in the string value. That didn't work either.

So I have windows 10 64 bit machines and the jar file needed to be placed on those computers. Once any user login, the jar file needs to run. But I couln't make that so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Java application at Windows startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

Write a batch file as follow ans save it as *.bat or *.cmd:

```
start javaw -Xmx200m -jar C:\Path\to\jarfile\TheJar.jar
```

Save the file created in the startup folder for all users, which should be `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

It is important to pay attention on the folder, because if your used Windows + R and `shell:startup` shortcut like I usually do, it will only work for the current logged user.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This time it doesn't work with the other user. Simply it just doesn't run the jar file. no error messages displayed.

Comment: Try to run the batch with with only `java -jar C:\Path\to\jarfile\TheJar.jar` and see is there will be any output. Or even use the same batch you were using and just putting it in the correct folder. When I first wrote the answer I imagined the folder was incorrect, probably `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: You are right! The user was able to run jar but I found out that the user cannot connect database. The other users need to connect database in order to run.

Comment: @dambros Does it work even with windows 10? What is "start" in the command? What would happen if I don't use start as prefix and just use javaw?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the issue you're having with the registry is permission based?

You should try putting the entry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` rather than in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955290/run-jar-file-on-startup) the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` "location does not suffer from permissions issues when run as an ordinary user".