# How can I make a java program always running?

Tags: java

How can I make a java program such that it is always running on the system (such as a daemon or service), but only allow one instance of the program to run? I would like it to start either when I run the program or when the system starts (either is fine).

Comment: You should clarify your question otherwise it is going to be closed.

Comment: It sounds like you may want it to run as a operating system service.  Does it need to be portable, or do you have a specific OS in mind?

Comment: Your question horribly formatted: overuse of punctuation marks, no capitalization, using SMS-like abbreviations ("shld" = "should"!). And besides that, it's not clear what you're really trying to do. So, please improve the formatting, and explain yourself more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: I rewrote it to what I assumed he was asking, but I might have been wrong so be sure to look at the revision to see if you can scry more from it than I did.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [commons-daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/)

Comment: I found this good to fit many more features including this, please see also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979451/auto-startup-for-java-desktop-application/5549910#5549910

Answer (score 1):

For First part of your Question you need to make  a thread running continuously,

for second part of your question  look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979451/auto-startup-for-java-desktop-application)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this to run a Java program as Windows service service : http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/ , with good results.