# JAVA: Opening an application when the user starts their computer

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have an application which has a purpose to run when the user first runs their computer.

However, I'd like to make a check box on the app that enables/disables the application loading when the system is started. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want your application execute in startup time of os?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create a service under windows. My suggestion is http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

This question has been discussed in SO time ago:

[Code for Auto starting a java application on windows startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025807/code-for-auto-starting-a-java-application-on-windows-startup)

[Auto startup for java desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979451/auto-startup-for-java-desktop-application)

However, maybe the easier solution is to create a batch file,like suggested in the first link, to run your application as the user logs in.

If you want to enable/disable the startup through a checkbox, the first and simplest solution that comes to my mind is this: you can make a method, invoked by the checkbox listener, that edits the batch file and enables/disables the line used to run the application, in the batch file.

If you have Windows 7, read [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html) tutorial.